# Aligning icons on the right hand side on Navbar Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Two issues:

1. I am trying to put the social icons more on the right beside 'reserve table' button but fail to do so
2. When i collapse the navbar the hamburger icon appears to the left of the 'reserve table'

In CSS classes nothing else just background color only so nothing in css file anything.

Any help or suggestions

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg core-header navbar-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> <img class="image_size" src="/images/logo1.png" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler bg-light" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link text-light mr-4">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link text-light mr-4">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link text-light">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a target="_blank" class="social_icons_items nav-item nav-link" href="https://youtube.com"><i class="fab fa-youtube text-white"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" class="social_icons_items nav-item nav-link" href="https://youtube.com"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reserve">
      <a target="_blank" class="button bg-white reserve-table" href="#">Reserve a Table</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I am trying to put the social icons more on the right beside 'reserve table' button but fail to do so.
   **Solution** 
   add class `ml-auto` to `<div class="navbar-nav">` which will move social icons to right side.
2. When i collapse the navbar the hamburger icon appears to the left of the 'reserve table' 
   **Solution**
   The reason that is happening because 'container' is flex container and when `navbar-collapse` div is shown (which has 100% width) expands and takes space which falls the reserve button. So you need to remove 'remove button' div within <nav> and keep it next to <nav> tag and style accordingly.

Hope this helps.